# login with google oauth returns "code: 1"

Tags: android, google-oauth, nativescript

i am trying to add a login with google to my android app. i installed nativescript-google-login ant did everything as i should and i redirected to the login window of google. but after i insert my details instead of getting the token and the info of the user i get this:

```
   {
       "provider": "google",
       "code": 1
   }
```

my google init looks like that:

```
google.GoogleLogin.init({
            google: {
                initialize: true,
                serverClientId: "<client id of a web client for oauth 2.0>",
                clientId: "<cient id for android>",
                isRequestAuthCode: true
            },
            activity: application.android.foregroundActivity
        })
```

what am i missing?

Comment: https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-social-login/issues/1

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for the quick repond. i already checked this thread, it was closed without actual answer. i just commented there hoping to get the it